# Create a vim script for django code completion, but fail, why?

Tags: python, django, bash, shell

I tried two ways to do code completion, one is OK, the other fails.

**OK one** does like below:

```
$> cd myDjangoProject/
myDjangoProject $> export PYTHONPATH="."
myDjangoProject $> DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings vim urls.py
```

Then ^x ^o can work well. But this method leads me repeatly do above when edit a file in project.

So an idea comes to me, why not create a script to do above automatically?

Refer to [Blog for django code completion in vim](http://www.belchak.com/2011/01/31/code-completion-for-python-and-django-in-vim/), this is exactly what I think, but I encounter a problem during my configuration.

**Fail one** below:

1. create a script in `/usr/bin` named `vim_wrapper`

   `#!/bin/bash`

   `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/myDjangoProject/"`

   `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="/path/to/myDjangoProject/settings" vim $@`
2. Add alias in `~/.bashrc`

   `alias vi="vim_wrapper"`

Restart terminal sesstion, command `vi /path/to/myDjangoProject/urls.py`, make a test `:python from django import db`, an Error happen says:

> ImportError: Could not import settings
>   'myDjangoProject/settings' (Is it on
>   sys.path?): Import by filename i s not
>   supported.

I don't know how to solve this. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the `vim_django` executable script in `/usr/bin`

Content in `vim_django` script:

`#!/bin/bash`

```
PROJECT=`python -c "import os; print os.getcwd().partition('Solutions')[2].split(os.sep)[1]"`
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/django-projects-parent/"
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$PROJECT.settings vim $@
```

Type `vim_django urls.py(or other files)` to edit in django project, `Ctrl-x & Ctrl-o` for code completion.

NOTE: In `PROJECT` settings, you may notice `Solutions` that is parent directory of all my django projects

Answer (score 0):

Try just settings `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings` as you did when it worked.  My hope is that your setting of `PYTHONPATH` will be sufficient.

Comment: Only set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` can not work well. As `Fail one` result says, `myDjangoProject is not on sys.path`, so I have to insert it into PYTHONPATH.